# How to convert uuid value to string using Azure devops GO implementation

Tags: go

I am using the azure devops package for go, to query a list of service endpoints.

I call the function:
func (client *ClientImpl) GetServiceEndpoints(ctx context.Context, args GetServiceEndpointsArgs) (*[]ServiceEndpoint, error)

The return type of serviceendpoint is defined as below
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-go-api/azuredevops@v1.0.0-b5/serviceendpoint#ServiceEndpoint

The return value I get from the module is in uuid format.
How can I get this as a useable format like resourceId=90d8caad-7150-4a36-9075-597479fe72f1
[image]

As you can see each value in the array contains a piece of the actual ID in azure devops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UUID type has a [String method](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid#UUID.String):

```
func (uuid UUID) String() string
```

Comment: thank you, ((*responseValue)[1].Id).String() worked perfectly
Learning Go so I did not expect to need to handle type conversion here